# Filter multiple data sets on excel using an external value or expression

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm currently part of a team doing some data analysis on a large data set that needs a LOT of manual end user feedback. Nothing too pretty.

As it stands. I've managed to pinpoint 8 data anomaly scenarios which I need to present to a trail user group, the simplest way will be to present the data in old-faithful excel.

[image]

On the AE Settings tab i want to have a cell where I can add a user name an all subsequent scenario tabs will be filtered.

**I've created an example to demonstrate:**
[image]

I need Bert to tell me that for example the correct name is
***Foo Bar Inc***, and in table 2 the correct code is ***234A***, but to not scare them with everyone else data I'd prefer an easy way to toggle between users.

**So my question in summary:**

How do I go about filtering multiple data sets on excel using an external value or expression.

Disclaimer.
I've attempted using advanced filter, but it doesn't retain the link to the filter value and data. EG. If i change the UserName (left in the picture) to Tom, the data sets wont update.

*Also I'm not sure if there is a separate ExcelOverflow group...*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach I would take, if I am understanding correctly, would be to build a change trigger on the cell on your AE Settings tab where you will change the filter all of the tables on each tab with that value.

In VBA, enter the code below to the code module for sheet "AE Settings"

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
 If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Sheets("AE Settings").Range("B13")) Is Nothing Then
    Sheets("Context").ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:= _
        Sheets("AE Settings").Range("B13").Value

    'duplicate the code here for each of the other sheets you want to filter 


 End If
 End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, this got me started in the right direction. I ended up modifying the answer though, as the "Is Nothing" part threw an exception. New If check.... IsEmpty(Sheets("AE Settings").Range("B13").Value